# cannot convert string to System.IO.Stream

Tags: c#, data-stream

In this C# Project, I have a JSON file in which I will be serializing data to. As I know, you create a StreamWriter and use that stream writer as a parameter. However, when I create the stream writer with the file path of the JSON file as the parameter, is gives me an error: `Argument 1: Cannot Convert String to System.IO.Stream`

Here is the file

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using ProjectObjects;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace level2
{
    public static class Data
    {
    static string selectedTeamName,selectedPlayerName;
    static Team selectedTeam = new Team("unknown");
    static Player selectedPlayer = new Player(" ");
    static List<Team> AllTeams = new List<Team>();


    public static void LoadFromCSV(string name, CSVType type)
    {
        string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        var MaindataFileDir = Path.Combine(dirinfo.FullName, "N/A");
        var file = new FileInfo(MaindataFileDir);

        if (type.Equals(CSVType.BJA))
        {

        }else if (type.Equals(CSVType.DefenseStats))
        {

        }else if (type.Equals(CSVType.HitStat))
        {

        }
    }

    public static void SerializeTeam(string filename)
    {
        string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        var MaindataFileDir = Path.Combine(dirinfo.FullName, "/Data/Datar.json");
        var file = new FileInfo(MaindataFileDir);
        string filepath = directory + "/Data/Datar.json";




        if (file.Exists)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(MaindataFileDir))
            using (var textwriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
            {
                //serializer.Serialize(textwriter, AllTeams);not finished
            }
        }

    }

    public static void DeserializeTeam()
    {
        string directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
        var MaindataFileDir = Path.Combine(dirinfo.FullName, "/Data/Datar.json");
        var file = new FileInfo(MaindataFileDir);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var writer = new StreamReader(MaindataFileDir))
            using (var textreader = new JsonTextReader(writer))
            {
                //serializer.Deserialize(textreader, AllTeams);not finished
            }
        }


    }
}

  }
```

The reason I'm having a hard time understanding what the issue is is that on MSDN there is an example extremely similar to what I'm doing.

From [Here:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "test.txt";
            string textToAdd = "Example text in file";

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
            writer.Write(textToAdd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case it's important, I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community. 
excuse my poor formatting. 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: What framework version are you targeting?  Is this UWP?

Comment: use File.ReadAllText() in StreamWriter.

Comment: 4.5.2 is the.net framework version. It was the default setting for me.